# Pycharm not highlighting variable syntax properly

Tags: python, pycharm

Referring to the ss, the syntax isn't highlighted properly. My colour of variblesm imports and brackets remain white and is classified as default text in pycharm. I've tried changing themes many times but it still resulted in the same issue, is there a way to fix this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Would you mind telling us, which color you have tried changing?

Comment: This question has to do with the IDE itself, not code, so you're probably going to find more help asking on a website specific to your IDE.

Comment: @ben Can you explain more about what you're trying to do?   I'm not sure I understand your problem.  Which syntax? What do you expect it to look like?  I'm not familiar with any setting in Pycharm related to "variblesm imports".

Answer (score 1):

Color schemes in pycharm can be a little wonky to understand at first.  I'm not sure what you mean by "variblesm imports" (sic) but the color of parenthesis (or any parameter for that matter) can be affected by a hierarchy of settings.

General -> Language Defaults -> Python

If you look in `Preferences > Editor > Color Scheme > Python > Braces and Operators` you'll find `Parentheses`.

If the setting is inherited, you'll have to go to `Language Defaults > Braces and Operators` to adjust the colors assuming you want all parentheses to have the same color regardless of language.

Otherwise, just uncheck inherit and set them as you wish.

[image]